# How to perform chmod() in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, file-permissions, chmod

What's the equivalent of C's:

```
 chmod(MY_FILE, 0777);
```

in Objective C? I am trying to write to an existing locked file without performing

```
chmod +x MY_FILE
```

on the terminal.

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C. Any C code you can run on iOS/OSX you can just copy paste into your objective-c file and it will work.

Comment: @Linuxios, except maybe for `int NSArray;` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo unless, of course, you avoid `@import`ing Cocoa.h, Foundation.h etc. But that would be some pretty boring Objective-C!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use C's `chmod()`.

Enter `man 2 chmod` in the terminal for the documentation and related functions.

Comment: IMHO, @newbieMACUser asked for the ObjC way to do this, not the C way, and the C way requires that you do library includes. With ObjC, [Amin Negm-Awad's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27478061/105539) is more suitable and requires no extra includes than the standard foundation stuff you get with a default Objective C file.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Cocoa's [`-setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:) to do this job.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{ NSFilePosixPermissions : @0666 }
                                 ofItemAtPath:… 
                                        error:&error];
```

Of course you need the rights to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using cocoa.

```
NSTask *changePerms = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[changePerms setLaunchPath:@"/bin/chmod"];
NSArray *chmodArgs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"666", @"/Users/abc/hello.txt", nil]; 
[changePerms setArguments:chmodArgs];
[changePerms launch];
```

This is another way using NSFileManager class

```
NSDictionary* attr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithShort:0766], NSFilePosixPermissions, NULL];

NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:attr ofItemAtPath:@"/Users/abc/Desktop/test.txt" error:&error];
```

Using system() call

```
system("chmod 777 /Users/abc/Desktop/test.txt");
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Your first code snippet is _awful_. There's really zero point in shelling out to an external command when `chmod()` is readily available.

Comment: Either use the raw C code or depend on any of the framework APIs. Both the options that I have given is using the frameworks.

Comment: Would probably be better to use `[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:___]` because chmod can handle a much larger value. For the proof, do `chmod u+s` on a file and then do `stat -r` on it and look at the third parameter. (At least it's the third on my Mac.) You'll see it's a number larger than what a signed short can hold, which is 32768, and what an unsigned short can hold, which is 65535. Pass that same number with chmod to another test file and you'll see that chmod accepts this unsigned long value.